# windows media player can't play DVDs even with codec installed

Tags: windows-xp, windows-media-player

I've got an old laptop (running WinXP) that my wife wants to use to watch DVDs on.  Windows Media player didn't have any codecs installed so I installed PowerDVD SE (for Windows XP) as linked from the WMP online help.

After installing, WMP will now list the DVD contents but can't play the DVDs.

It can play the audio track, but doesn't show anything.

The DVDs play fine on other players.

"Microsoft Windows XP Video Decoder Checkup Utility" says the codec is installed OK and should be working.

Knowing nothing about video formats or codecs or the like what do you suggest?

Is it worth trying other codecs? or should I just try a different player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just install [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/), it plays just about anything. It's a popular player, no spam or anything.